# Plotting points with different marker and different plotlegend

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Currently i'm stuck at problem, where i have a sets of points, and I wish to plot these point with different plot markers, and also with different plot legend. The code is the following:

```
    filteredLength={{356., 362., 375., 339., 346., 351., 357., 328., 347.}, {377., 365., 
      388., 336., 361., 359., 323., 359., 381.}}

    Rsquared={{0.999189, 0.999533, 0.998305, 0.992933, 0.999151, 0.999383, 
      0.999122, 0.996901, 0.999277}, {0.999497, 0.999238, 0.98825, 
      0.998982, 0.999436, 0.999387, 0.998706, 0.999248, 
      0.999491}}
filteredName={{"Downhill_Simplex", "Downhill_Simplex_weight_1_10", 
      "Downhill_Simplex_weight_2_10", "Downhill_Simplex_weight_3_10", 
      "Hooke_Jeves", "Hooke_Jeves_wieght_1_10", "Hooke_Jeves_wieght_2_10",
       "Hooke_Jeves_weight_3_10", "ASA"}, {"Downhill_simplex", 
      "Downhill_simplex_weight_1_10", "Downhill_simplex_weight_2_10", 
      "Downhill_simplex_weight_3_10", "Hooke_Jeves",
      "Hooke_Jeves_weight_1_10", "Hooke_Jeves_weight_2_10", 
      "Hooke_Jeves_weight_3_10", "ASA"}}
    toPlot = List[];
    Do[
     AppendTo[toPlot, Thread[{filteredLength[[i]], Rsquared[[i]]}]], {i, 
      1, 6}]
    plots = Table[Symbol["plot" <> ToString@i], {i, 1, 2}];

    Do[
     Do[
      plots[[i]] = 
        ListPlot[toPlot[[i, j]], Joined -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
         PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
         FrameStyle -> Directive[11], 
         GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
         FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[14], PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
         PlotLegends -> ArrayReshape[filteredName[[i]], {9, 1}]];
      , {j, 1, 2}]
     , {i, 1, 2}]
```

I hope you can provide me a solution.
Thank you in advance: David

Comment: Please boil this down to a minimal working example. First two issues: `toPlot` needs to be defined first (I guess as `toPlot={}`), and `ImageSize -> 15 cm` is erratic. Even when fixed, your [output](https://imgur.com/a/m9ZLoNt) doesn't say what you are after. Use words to describe your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = Legended[{{#, #2}}, #3] & @@@ (Join @@ 
     Thread /@ Transpose[{filteredLength, Rsquared, filteredName}]);
ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 8}]
```

[image]